# Replace returning Optional Instance from findAny or findFirst with Custom Optional Class

Tags: java, api, java-8, option-type

I do not know who was responsible for that kind of work, but for me Javas Optional seems not ready for the production. It seems that the Java Creators just were tiered to finish the work and the result is a not ready Optional Class with a lack of many functions.

For example consider the ifPresent method. The return type is void but it could be a instance of this just to have something similar like peek in the stream framework. It is not a big deal to put return this in a method but to not do this means that the thinking about optional was not production ready.

Another example is the lack of checked methods that consider that the mapping or filtering may throw an exception resulting in a lot of try catch boilerplate. Instead doing so, they have just add a UncheckedIOException. The boilerplate still remain. I mean what is so difficult to add checked Methods as well?

A can give you a lot of more examples but I do not want to invest my energy and time in a non complete class like optional. I started to create a replacement for optional that I may publish as an open source project in the future. The only lack in my implementation is the possibility to combine my optional class with the stream framework where methods like findAny or findFirst returning the Optional type that I want to replace. This problem I need to face because optional needs to be final of course.

I do not have any idea what would be the best to handle the situation so I hope there is someone here who could give me a nice hint.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I have really the impression that some people here are too lazy to read my post, so I want to clear things out.

If I say that ifPresent should return this of course I cant mean the value that Optional is holding. It means the "this" instance so that you can chain with next commands, the same like peek in the stream framework.

```
public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
    if (value != null)
        consumer.accept(value);
}
```

This is the original code of Optional that is currently used in Java8. If you would have though about that functionality, you would write it in this way:

```
public OptionalReplacement<T> ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
    requireNonNull(consumer);
    if (isPresent()) {
        consumer.accept(value);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Then you will be able to write something like

```
OptionalReplacement.of(nullable)
    .ifPresent(notNull-> System.out.println(notNull))
    .ifPresent(notNull-> System.out.println(notNull))
```

There is no reason to make ifPresent as void and returning this gives you more flexibility to chain. Are you able to that kind of chaining with the current optional class, no!

The next topic are the checked exceptions. Because some people have no fantasy I will give you an example of a possible map that handle checked exceptions.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}

public <U, E extends Exception> OptionalReplacement<U> checkedMap(Class<E> exceptionClass, CheckedFunction<? super T, ? extends U, E> mapper) throws E {
    requireNonNull(exceptionClass);
    requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();
    else {
        return OptionalReplacement.of(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

So you become able to write something like that

```
OptionalReplacement.of(nullable)
        .checkedMap(IOException.class, notNull -> {
            throw new IOException();
        });
```

Which makes much more sense than

```
    Optional.of(nullable)
            .map(notNull -> {
                try {
                    throw new IOException();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

Also a comment to the votes that are mentioned in the comments. Votes are good and fine, but the mass of people was never a indicator for quality. I got good votes for stupid questions and I got negative votes for intelligent questions, so I am fine.

The user should think more about the problem I try to face here instead distracting with not important stuff.

Comment: I don't believe Optional can be replaced this way, you could create a wrapper for an Optional.

Comment: I also dont think there could be a clean replacement but what would be the least evil

Comment: A wrapper which is a drop in replacement, most likely.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? If you have suggestions or comments on Java libraries design, you better write to core-libs-dev@openjdk.java.net. But regarding what you're saying: 1) Optional gets a [`stream()` method](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) in 9; 2) Checked exceptions in Java are controversial, it's much greater topic than `Optional`, and it would require a lot of effort to re-design them.

Comment: @LachezarBalev The return type of `ifPresent` *is* `void`. The point about exception is that the `mapper` can't throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 9):

> For example consider the ifPresent method. The return type is void but it could be a instance of this just to have something similar like peek in the stream framework. It is not a big deal to put return this in a method but to not do this means that the thinking about optional was not production ready.

`Optional` is there to abstract away the `null` value. And it does it well: if `value` is `null`, you will not be able to get `value` from any of the methods.

Now, which value should `ifPresent` return if the `value` is `null`? This can't be `value` as this will break the main principle of `Optional`. So what should be returned? Options are:

- supply the value like in `orElse` and likes;
- have `void` as the return type.

`ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer, T other)` is ugly so the design choice is quite obvious.

Next, why would you need a return value if you feed it to a consumer? Why can't you do whatever you want to do with the value in the consumer?

> Another example is the lack of checked methods that consider that the mapping or filtering may throw an exception resulting in a lot of try catch boilerplate. Instead doing so, they have just add a UncheckedIOException. The boilerplate still remain. I mean what is so difficult to add checked Methods as well?

Impossible. Assuming your mapping function throws some checked exception. How do you expect this checked exception to appear in the `Optional.map` signature? Options are:

- `throws Exception` with `try`/`catch` block polluting everything;
- `map(mapper, exceptionHandler)` which is no better.

So the whole lambdas thing can only function with unchecked exceptions, everything else results in pretty ugly code.

> A can give you a lot of more examples but I do not want to invest my energy and time in a non complete class like optional.

`Optional` in Java 8 is very similar to [`Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) in Guava, it's there for ages and is well received.

The worst design decision for `Optional` is probably the `get` method which leads a lot of people to write `if (o.isPresent()) { T value = o.get(); ... }` type of code.

You may want to reconsider your judgement of `Optional`.

> I started to create a replacement for optional that I may publish as an open source project in the future.

A *stand-alone* re-imagined re-implementation of `Optional` will be pretty useless. And there is no way you can replace the `Optional` used by the Java collection framework.

> I do not have any idea what would be the best to handle the situation so I hope there is someone here who could give me a nice hint.

A nice hint would be to ask about specific problems you've encountered with `Optional` and how they can be solved better in code. As you can see from the downvotes, a better, more respectful tone would not do any damage either.